# Code corrupt, program still works

Tags: vb.net

Opened my project today, and my .vb is split into three columns. I'm not sure what the first is, but the second is groups of two zeros and the third is a bunch of periods. The program still runs, the designer is visible, but the code is completely corrupt and the compiler won't run the code in visual studio.

[image]

Comment: Try to open your code (eg. Form1.vb) in Notepad. Is it still corrupted?

Comment: Once you've recovered from this (worst case, you can reconstruct your code from the still-viable program using something like [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx)), now might be a very good time to look at Source Control (and backups, if you don't have them), so you can see precisely what's changed to cause this.

Comment: It's just a blank file.

Comment: That looks like the binary editor in VS.  Have you tried closing the file and selecting it in Solution Explorer and then hitting F7 (View Code)?

Comment: That's what I'm looking at.